# Angular JS resolve function with service that calls backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a resolve function, that validates a token in backend and returns success true or success false. IF false, it redirects to an error page, and if validated, it loads the page.

```
 .when('/resetPassword/:id/:token', {
      templateUrl: 'site/resetPassword/resetPassword.html',
      controller: 'resetPasswordCtrl',
      entitled: 'reset',
      authenticate: true,
      resolve: {
        isValid: ['resetTokenService','$route' , function(resetTokenService, $route) {
          return resetTokenService.validate($route.current.params.id, $route.current.params.token);
        }]
      }
    })
```

This is the service:

```
app.service('resetTokenService', function (userResourceResourceFactory, $rootScope, $location, CONFIG, $http) {
  var self = this;
  var errorMsg;
  $rootScope.errorObject = {errorMessage: null, errorCode: null,errorTime :null,errorStackTrace: null,url:window.location.href,partnerCode:null};

  this.validate = function(id, token) {
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: CONFIG.MSA_URL + '/validate/' + id +'/' + token,
    }).success(function (data) {
      if (data.success) {
        return true;
      } else if (!data.success){
        switch (data.error) {
          case 'expired':
            errorMsg = 'This link has expired. Please request a new one.';
            break;
          default : errorMsg = 'This link is invalid.';
        }
        $rootScope.errorObject.errorMessage=errorMsg;
        $location.path('ErrorPage');
        return false;
      }
    }).error(function () {
      $rootScope.errorObject.errorMessage=errorMsg;
      $location.path('ErrorPage');
      return false;
    });
  };
});
```

It works well; however, if invalid, the password page flashes momentarily while it goes through the if and case statements. Therefore it is "resolved" when the backend call comes back, not when it returns true or false.

I am wondering how to make the page not flash and have the resolve {} function not do anything until it returns true or false / redirects

Comment: did you take a look at `ngCloak`

Comment: I added a <div ng-cloak> to the html file, but it still flashes the page

Comment: In your resetTokenService.validate() function, shouldn't the $http call have a return e.g. return $http(...)?

Answer (score 0):

The `validate` function should be returning a promise. Currently, I believe your route is actually being resolved immediately (not when the backend call comes back), since your `validate` function doesn't return anything. This means that right now, it is probably always returning `undefined` to your controller.

You can start by returning the promise that comes from `$http` to see if things behave as you need:

```
this.validate = function(id, token) {
    return $http({ ... });
}
```

However, this may not be enough because it looks like you need to redirect sometimes even if the promise from `$http` is a success. Whenever you want to prevent the state from loading, the promise you returned should be rejected.

So you may end up needing to return a promise that you manually create using the `$q` service, and then either resolving it (possibly with `true`, if you need the controller to see that boolean value), or rejecting it (in which case the controller will never load).

In the past, when using `ui-router` I've sometimes had to do hacky things like do the actual redirection inside a `$timeout`, or add an event handler to catch the routing error that happens when a promise is rejected, and do the redirection in there. I'm not sure if you'll have to do either of those in this case, but figured I'd mention it.